# Multiplicative Jordan decomposition in Lie group

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $V$ be a real vector space. It is known that any $g \in GL(V)$ is uniquely written $g = g_s g_u$ with $g_s$ semisimple, $g_u$ nilpotent, and $g_s g_u = g_u g_s$.

Let $G \subseteq GL(V)$ be a Lie subgroup, maybe connected, maybe semisimple. I would like to know if the following is true:

1. The Jordan decomposition is stable in $G$: if $g \in G$, then $g_s, g_u \in G$.
2. The Jordan decomposition is independent of the linear representation of $G$: if $\rho \colon G \to GL(W)$ is any faithful representation, then $\rho(g_s) = \rho(g)_s$ and $\rho(g_u) = \rho(g)_u$.

I am aware that the analogous statements for semisimple Lie algebras are true. But it doesn't seem trivial to derive 1. from the Lie algebra version, unless assumption like exp is surjective.

Here are precise questions:

- Apparently groups $G$ that satisfy 1. are called splittable according to [link](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82100812.pdf). Is it true that any (connected?) semisimple Lie group is splittable? Is there an "easy" proof? (e.g. don't assume G algebraic)
- Does it make things harder to ask for the finer decomposition $g = g_e g_h g_u$ with $g_e$ elliptic and $g_h$ hyperbolic? Apparently [this paper](https://www.scielo.cl/pdf/proy/v30n1/art11.pdf) claims to prove for the first time such a decomposition in a semisimple Lie group (Thm 3.7 and Cor 3.8) but I'm a bit wary.

Comment: on page 83 in Borel's book "Linear algebra groups" a statement  similar to 1 is proved for any affine algebraic group. Have you read this proof?